# Another application of Riesz-Thorin

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and take $A$ to be an $n \times n$ matrix. Suppose that $$\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{ij}| \leq K, \quad \text{and} \quad\sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}| \leq K$$ for all $i,j = 1, \dots, n$. Then, for all $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ we get $$\|Ax\|_p \leq K \|x\|_p.$$

I believe one can apply some version of the Riesz-Thorin Interpolation Theorem, but it escapes me. However it seems to escape me as it does not seem applicable as a first glance. Please help me. Btw could this be done without RTT?

Comment: check that the assumptions correspond to matrix norms with suitable $p$

Comment: Apply the proof of the Schur test adjusted to $\ell^p$ norm.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$, $u_{ij}=|a_{ij}|^{1/p}|x_j|$ and $v_{ij}=|a_{ij}|^{1/q}$. Then
\begin{align*}
|(Ax)_i|
=\left|\sum_ja_{ij}x_j\right|
&\le\sum_j|a_{ij}x_j|
=\sum_ju_{ij}v_{ij}\\
&\le\left(\sum_ju_{ij}^p\right)^{1/p}
\left(\sum_jv_{ij}^q\right)^{1/q}\\
&=\left(\sum_j|a_{ij}||x_j|^p\right)^{1/p}
\left(\sum_j|a_{ij}|\right)^{1/q}\\
&\le\left(\sum_j|a_{ij}||x_j|^p\right)^{1/p}K^{1/q}.\\
\end{align*}
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\|Ax\|_p^p
&=\sum_i|(Ax)_i|^p\\
&\le\sum_i\sum_j|a_{ij}||x_j|^pK^{p/q}\\
&=\sum_j\sum_i|a_{ij}||x_j|^pK^{p/q}\\
&\le\sum_jK|x_j|^pK^{p/q}\\
&=K^{p/p+p/q}\sum_j|x_j|^p\\
&=K^p\|x\|_p^p.\\
\end{align*}